# Normal map causing abrupt change in shading across UV islands

Tags: unreal, 3dsmax, normal-mapping, unreal-4

[image]

As you can see in the image above, there is a big change in shading past the uv island on the end. i have no idea what caused this, but I can reproduce my steps as best i can.

1. Model high poly in zbrush
2. Duplicate and decimate the duplicate
3. Export both to 3ds max and align them
4. UV the low
5. make a cage by duplicating the low and adding a push modifier
6. export the low, high and cage
7. bake in xnormal
8. add material in max with 100% normal strength plugged into a normal bump with the source linked to the texture
9. Change viewport to realistic materials with maps

No idea why this is happening. I used tangent space any ideas?

Comment: I read an article that said object space should work which it did but tangent are screwed up. I think this is a related article http://polycount.com/discussion/108442/normal-map-produces-ugly-seams

Comment: been stuck on this for days now.. :(